# Does MySQL automatically limit affected rows, when unique key is used as query condition?

Tags: mysql

Let's take a look at this SQL query to a MySQL database:

```
UPDATE `messages` SET `read`=1 WHERE `id`=1234;
```

Let's assume that `messages` is a really long table and `id` is auto increasing and primary key.

My question is:

**Does MySQL automatically stop searching, when it finds one message with `id=1234`? Or in other words: is there any point using `LIMIT` in query like this one?**

Comment: It doesn't "search" at all.  It uses the primary key's index to find that specific record and update it.  Are you noticing some other behavior?  What isn't working as expected?

Comment: sorry, I'm not very familiar with how database engines work. My guess was that for a query like this, db engine loops across all table rows and checks if all conditions given in query are fulfilled; so e.g. if db engine would find a match for this query in a first row, it would check all the other rows in the table anyway, right? Does it work another way for primary keys?

Comment: MySQL 5.6+ supports [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) on `UPDATE`.. One way to check how MySQL handles the `UPDATE` queries.. Fully explaining how a database engine works is very broad..

Comment: @Lis: That would be a very ineffecient design for a database.  It sounds like your question is based on a false premise and doesn't really make sense.  If you're interested in learning how relational databases work, there are volumes of literature and research on the subject.  MySQL is also open source: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server

Comment: *"Does MySQL automatically stop searching, when it finds one message with id=1234? Or in other words: is there any point using LIMIT in query like this one?"* **NO** there isn't a point of using `LIMIT` here..Also generally speaking when using `LIMIT` you should also use a `ORDER BY` on a column which has a primary or unique key or you know it has unique values otherwise the results will be non deterministic (random)

Comment: .. The reason behide that is that SQL tables and resultsets are by SQL standards definition **orderless** so the SQL executioner can deliver the records in a order what it "thinks" is best or best suited.. Like mentioned to get deterministic (fixed) always results use `ORDER BY` on the primary key or unique key column it does not matter if you use one columns or more be sure you add it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does MySQL automatically stop searching, when it finds one message
>   with id=1234?

Because `id` is a primary key, it has an index. MySQL uses that index to find the row to update. It isn't *searching* in the sense of looking at many rows. It simply random-accesses the table at the right row. Because it's a primary key, MySQL knows it must update only one row. As we say in Boston, Mass, USA, it's wicked fast.

> Is there any point using LIMIT in query like this
>   one?

No.

Don't try to outsmart SQL. It's a *declarative* language, not *procedural*. Use your queries, like your `UPDATE`, to *describe* what you want. MySQL has, literally, thousands of programmer-years in the code it uses to figure out the fastest procedure to use.